# Update not working for Visual Force Page fields

Tags: apex, visualforce, update, upsert

I am writing a class to update a record with data from visual force page if it exists in contact, if it does not it will insert a row.I am using Update and Insert statements for this purpose.Looks like the Id of current page not retrieved for update operation. I am using this to update the record.
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')
I am using getrecord() to insert a row
I am using Try Catch to perform Update and Insert. It always performs Insert.

I put Insert code in Catch because it is giving 'No rows in list to assign to SObject' error for SELECT statement .Let me know if you need code for the page.

Thank you for the help.

***Code for Apex Class***

```
 public class thankyoupageredirectext {


 public contact con{get;set;}                    
 public contact con1{get;set;}     

 string Other_In_Kind_Donation__c,Scoop_value,description_value;
  string Clothing_In_Kind_Donation_value;
  string contact_url;
 string Food_In_Kind_Donation_value;         

 public thankyoupageredirectext (ApexPages.StandardController stdController)    {   

 con1 = (contact)stdController.getRecord();     

  }     

 public PageReference save(){  

     try
  {
     con =  [SELECT Id,firstname, Title,lastname,description,The_Scoop__c,email,Other_In_Kind_Donation__c,Clothing_In_Kind_Donation__c,Food_In_Kind_Donation__c FROM contact  WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
   update con;     
   retun null;
}
  catch (exception e)
{

  this.con = con1;
  insert con;
  return  null;

  }                      


  }

}
```

***Code for Visual Force Page***

```
 <apex:page standardController="contact"    extensions="thankyoupageredirectext"   sidebar="false" showHeader="false" >

<style type="text/css">

 .myClass {
  color:Black;
  font-size: 30px;          
  text-align:center;
}

</style>

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
  <apex:outputLabel value="In-Kind Donation" styleClass="myClass"/>

     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.firstname}"/> 
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.lastname}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Organization__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.Title}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.email}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.phone}"/>      
     <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingStreet}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingState}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCountry}"/>             
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.Clothing_In_Kind_Donation__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.Food_In_Kind_Donation__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{! contact.The_Scoop__c}" required="true"/>

 </apex:pageBlockSection>       
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom" >          
<apex:commandbutton value="Submit" action="{!save}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>     
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please add VFP also

Comment: Added code for VFP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better gather the data during page load and assign in the controller Constructor.

And finally perform `upsert` operation (which is combination of `insert` and `update`) in Save method. Refer [Upsert Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_upsert.htm) in documentation.

> **Controller**

```
public contact con{get;set;}
public thankyoupageredirectext (ApexPages.StandardController stdController)    
{
    con = (contact)stdController.getRecord();     
}     



 public PageReference save()
 { 
     try
    {   upsert con;     
        return null;
    }
     catch (exception ex)
    {
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, ex.getMessage());
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Change the `<apex:inputField/>` value attribute from `Contact` to `con` (which is Contact instance)

> **Visualforce**

```
<apex:form>
     <apex:inputField value="{! con.firstname}"/> 
     <apex:inputField value="{! con.lastname}"/>
     <!--  add other attributes -->

</apex:form>
```

Updated based on comments

Put id explicitly in the parameter

```
PageReference pg = new PageReference(ApexPages.CurrentPage);
pg.getParameters().put('id', controller.getId());
pg.setRedirect(true);
return pg;
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu. I modified the code as you mentioned. I tested it. After a new row is inserted, if I update any fields on the page , it is updating the record . But if I open the page again or refresh the page and try to update the existing row , it's creating new row again. Not sure what is causing this and what is missing??

Comment: I think, if you open the page again or refresh the page, id attribute in the url is missing

Comment: Yes, that's true.Any work around??

Comment: then try to pass explicitly id into that parameter

Comment: Santanu, Where should I place this in the class.Is it before getRecord()

Comment: Santanu,Yes I placed the code which you gave but still its not updating the record when I entered in a refreshed form page.I really Thankyou for you time.Let me know if anything I need to do with the code.